# Change of a scalar field/vector field

Tags: derivatives, vector-fields, calculus

In my book the following is written:

> The change of a scalar field $du$ in an arbitrary direction, given by an infinitesimal vector with an arbitrary direction $d\vec r$ is calculated:
> $$du=u(\vec r + d\vec r) - u(\vec r)= d\vec r\cdot\nabla u.$$
> And for the vector field $\vec v$ we have:
> $$d\vec v= \vec v(\vec r + d\vec r) - \vec v(\vec r)= (d\vec r \cdot\nabla) \vec v.$$

Can someone explain:

1. How do we derivate this!
2. A visualization of both of them! or a link to the asked topic.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question? We can migrate it for you.

Comment: Well this happens to be a math related question, but my Bachelor is in Physics. Idk what it is meant with migration there, if it is to just send my question in that section then ok, but ofc i want to remain here

Answer (score 0):

It's a direct application of the chain rule for multi-variable calculus. Perhaps using summatory notation clarifies further the point:
$$
dv^{i}=v^{i}\left(\boldsymbol{r}+d\boldsymbol{r}\right)-v^{i}\left(\boldsymbol{r}\right)\simeq\sum_{k}dr^{k}\frac{\partial v^{i}}{\partial r^{k}}
$$
As to an intuitive picture of what it is, it is how much the i-th component of $\boldsymbol{v}$ varies in the direction of the small displacement vector $d\boldsymbol{r}$, so it's natural to project gradient of $v^i$ along such small vector.

Comment: But how do i operate or expand this : d$\vec v(\vec r))$ = d$\vec v$/d$\vec r$ . How do i derivate with a vector as my variable ?

Comment: If the basis vectors are fixed, consider it as three functions depending on three variables, and work it out component by component of $\boldsymbol{v}$. If you're working in curvilinear coordinates, the rule must be generalised. But let's not get into that.